# grails deploy many GB of assets with asset plugin

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, assets

I have a lot of assets (about 3GB) that I want to publish public (available in /assets). BUT I don't want them to be included in the war because the war will be exploding and I don't know how the server will behave when it need to deploy shuch a big war file.

I tried to set the storage path to

```
grails.assets.storagePath = "/var/assets"
```

it looks like all files that are still in my assets (in the war) are copied there as well, so I have the files I put there (manually) and the one that have been copied in the deploy process. But when I call

http://foo.bar/assets/some-file-it-put-there-manually.jpg

I am getting a 404

Can somebody tell my what is the best practice for my need?